# Pandas read_csv EOF inside string starting at line

Tags: python, pandas, eof

I am facing an issue with pandas read_csv. I have a file, which contains " as field value. In reality, that should not be the case, but I have no influence on file generation, due to which I have to find a workaround.

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 15345

I found a issue report on this on Git ([link here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5500)), where they suggest to use delimiter that is used for "sep" parameter also for "quotechar". In this case, structure of file gets messed up.

Another thing that I did was to add an exception to this, which will run code for rest of the files, but I will keep having that issue for that particular type of files.

Command that I use to read CSV file:

```
df_new = pd.read_csv(file_path_name, sep=";", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Any idea of a workaround for this (e.g. ignore line with this issue)? One way I guess would be to use csv library to remove that line (or replace " with something else), but I would like to keep it simple and do as much as possible within pandas.

Python version: 3.6.2

Pandas version: 0.21.0

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Can you post sample erroneous records from your csv file? I asked because I'm trying to replicate your issue but did not encounter it.

Comment: `error_bad_lines=False` is a workaround. But a solution would involve seeing the row that is causing the loading to error out.

Comment: Hello!

I have tried this and this only solves an issue, where there would be too many/few fields in a line, it would still not read a file into a dataframe when EOF issue occurs

@user8505495: here is a sample record that is causing the issue (delimiter set to ;)
";";testmail@mail.com;PRI;BUS;0;1;0.00;;;;;ACTIVE;1;;;0;TRUE;GEO;FALSE;1

Comment: Did you try what is described here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016037/pandas-parsererror-eof-character-when-reading-multiple-csv-files-to-hdf5) that is adding quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE?

Comment: @user8505495, thank you for that, it did indeed solve my issue :) I saw this setting before, but I had no idea what it does, so I did not even try it. One thing to mention for anyone, who would find this useful - using quoting=3 in to_csv command was causing errors for me (missing escape char), so I only used this option for read_csv. Thank you again for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas ParserError EOF character when reading multiple csv files to HDF5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016037/pandas-parsererror-eof-character-when-reading-multiple-csv-files-to-hdf5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would just like to point out that suggestion from @user8505495 worked (thank you again).

Basically just adding parameter `quoting=3` to `read_csv`. Using same parameter in `to_csv` caused and error (missing escape character). One option is to set up `escapechar` parameter, or just not use `quoting` parameter for it.