# Pandas DataFrame.to_csv() doesn't output all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a large dataframe with ~450 columns. I need to export it to csv, and for that I use the next command:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='\t', header=False, index=False, na_rep='null')
```

The resulting file is missing several of the trailing columns.
I tried to update pandas display options, but that didn't solve the problem:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

*Background*:
I need to export data from one DB table to the other, adding one more column on the fly. I export data to csv, create a dataframe from it, add a column, and then need to export it to csv again to import into the resulting table.

Comment: Why can't you copy the dataframe and a column to the new df?

Comment: Have you tried setting <header=True> to check which columns are missing? alternatively, try using <sep=','> and see if issue persists.

Comment: Maybe it goes wrong when you're importing the file from DB to a df? Or do you have the right amount of columns when you do the import and it only goes wrong with the final export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the original data had a quotation mark somewhere. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857126/1434709) to another question helped me sort it out. I resolved the problem with:

```
pd.read_csv(file_obj, sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```