# using dask, Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line

Tags: python, dask

When using dask to read one csv file, showed error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 680
```

How to resolve this problem.

finally, I used from_pandas method.

```
dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
```

but, I should read csv file with pandas at first, which have to occupy memory.

Comment: May be helpful. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016037/pandas-parsererror-eof-character-when-reading-multiple-csv-files-to-hdf5).

Comment: What happen when you try to read it with `pandas`? Isn't a `delimeter` problems?

Comment: I didn't met problem. Finally, I read csv with pandas at first, then convert pandas to dask.