# Why I get strange error when trying to read csv file in colab?

Tags: pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

I get strange error when trying to read csv file in colab, however no error appears when I do it on Jupiter notebook with same dataframe. Here is the error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 75397
```

When I do `pd.read_csv("train.csv")` on Jupiter it works perfectly, but in colab this error appears. How to fix it?

Comment: Have to tried to specify encoding? e.g. `pd.read_csv("train.csv", encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: @Marco_CH yeah it says ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: unexpected end of data```

Comment: Is it `utf-8` or maybe another one?

Comment: @Marco_CH its utf-8 for sure

Comment: Ok, then could you try `pd.read_csv("train.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: Or `pd.read_csv("train.csv", quoting=3, error_bad_lines=False, encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: @Ir8_mind, you may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016037/pandas-parsererror-eof-character-when-reading-multiple-csv-files-to-hdf5

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. What happens is that it's reading the HTML encoded file. This is how I solved it:

1. Open the GitHub repository page in your web browser.
2. Click on the dataset file you want to read from the GitHub repository. A preview of the file will open.
3. You will find a "Raw" button close to the upper right corner of the file preview. ...
4. Copy this URL and paste in your google colab using this code.

`import pandas as pd`
`df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/publicfile.csv')`