Errors Reading CSV Python despite it looking fine in Excel
Good morning. I'm working on a project and am having issues reading a CSV on a file with more than 36,000 rows. When I run it normally:
df = pd.read_csv('File.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', dtype='str')
#FYI, this is the only encoding to get anywhere. Plus, I downloaded this report from Salesforce, and I ensured the encodings match.
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 21276

To test this, I run this cell:
import csv

file_path = 'File.csv'

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 21275:  # since Python is zero-indexed
            print(f'Line 21276: {line}')
            x = line
            print(x)
            print(len(x))
            break

Here is the output (actual info replaced with placeholder).
Line 21276: ['FIRST LAST', 'Company', '12345', 'Place', 'Place', 'Place', '123456', '123456', '1_2_34', '', 'Location', '', 'Thing', 'None', '', '12.345', '0.000', 'Something', 'Status', '1/2/2034 12:00 AM', '3/45/6789', '', '', '', '', '']
26

I've opened up the CSV file on Excel and the columns run from A to Z, so that's 26 columns. Everything lines up.
I've tried this and got a different issue:
df = pd.read_csv('File.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', dtype='str', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 27 fields in line 535, saw 28

I diagnosed this similarly.
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if i == 534:  # since Python is zero-indexed
            print(f'Line 535: {line}')
            x = line
            print(len(x.split(',')))
            break

Line 535: "FIRST LAST","Company","12345","Place","Place","Place","12345","12345","3_4_56","","Place","","Thing","None","","0000.000","0.000","Something","Word","2/34/5678 12:00 PM","","","","0000.00","",""

28

It looks like adding the QUOTE_NONE progresses troubleshooting, but adds columns. I checked this row in Excel and verified there are only 26 columns.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

This is possibly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016037/pandas-parsererror-eof-character-when-reading-multiple-csv-files-to-hdf5 - do you have a string with a single quote mark inside your CSV somewhere? That would also explain why QUOTE_NONE helps. You can also try the on_bad_lines='skip' option for read_csv, but you probably want to fix your data source instead as that may skip a line.

Maybe try setting engine='python'? Not sure how it's different to the default parsing engine, but it seems to be able to solve similar issues.

So my CSV file has over 30,000 rows. When I used the find function in Excel, I found three rows that had the double quotes. There are a few apostrophes too, when it relates to a business (ex: McDonald's).

@IgnatiusReilly Interesting. So when I tried that, I got a new error I've never seen before.
ParserError: unexpected end of data

Thank you. I fixed the error. It looked like it was a poor download attempt. It looks like it failed at some point and had much fewer rows than it should have. Re-downloading this allowed me to read_csv normally.
